# Find the average of a list

Tags: python-2.7

I am try to calculate a 'strange' list average on Python 2.7.
The list is:

```
list = ['', '0.00066', '0.00066', '0.00066', '0.00066']
```

The cmd I use to get sum first: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list)`
but I get a wrong return: sum of list is:  `0.000660.000660.000660.00066`

Please advice how to get the average of the list.

Comment: You have to convert them to floats...

Comment: Thanks Andrew, just to confirm, you mean to float each item in the list first?

Comment: in your lambda, you are doing concatenation because you have strings. Do `float(x) + float(y)` or map float to every element. Make sure to filter out the first element because it's an invalid float

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to float with the twist that the empty string will raise an error. Luckily, you can filter out the blank before the conversion.

```
>>> list = ['', '0.00066', '0.00066', '0.00066', '0.00066']
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, (float(i) for i in list if i))
0.00264
```

As an aside, python has functional versions of operators you can use in cases like this. And of course, `sum` is already purpose built to add things up.

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.add, (float(i) for i in list if i))
0.00264
>>> sum(float(i) for i in list if i)
0.00264
```